# The checking is always true after first loop in VBA in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

The "Check" somehow is always 0 after first loop, I keep debugging but still cannot find out why. Any idea? The data suppose to make "check" be 0 sometimes but not all the time.

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Amity")
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Opportunity")
    Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("SalesForceDonor")
    Set rs4 = db.OpenRecordset("Donor")

    While Not rs.EOF
        check = 0

        While Not rs3.EOF
            If rs("Donor_Code") = rs3("Donor_Code") Then
                check = 1
            End If
            rs3.MoveNext
        Wend

        If check = 0 Then
            rs4.AddNew
            rs4![Donor_Code] = rs![Donor_Code]
            rs4.Update
        End If

        rs2.AddNew
        rs2![Donor_Code] = rs![Donor_Code]
        rs2![Donation_name] = rs![Donation_name]
        rs2.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs3.Close
    rs4.Close
    rs2.Close
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: rs3.EOF is always true: the table "SalesForceDonor" contains no records? As you are adding Donor_Code in the table Donor via rs4.

Answer (score 1):

I've found somethig that must be corrected, adding rs3.MoveFirst for each record of rs:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
    Dim check
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Amity")
    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Opportunity")
    Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("SalesForceDonor")
    Set rs4 = db.OpenRecordset("Donor")

    While Not rs.EOF
        check = 0

        rs3.MoveFirst ' <= here we move to the first record of rs3!!!

        Do While Not rs3.EOF
            If rs("Donor_Code") = rs3("Donor_Code") Then
                check = 1
                Exit Do
            End If
            rs3.MoveNext
        Loop

        If check = 0 Then
            rs4.AddNew
            rs4![Donor_Code] = rs![Donor_Code]
            rs4.Update
        End If

        rs2.AddNew
        rs2![Donor_Code] = rs![Donor_Code]
        rs2![Donation_name] = rs![Donation_name]
        rs2.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs3.Close
    rs4.Close
    rs2.Close
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: @Teemo, if this response solves your problem, please dont forget to check it as **accepted** in order to make it easier for visitors of the site to view it.